# Can an INSERT operation result in a deadlock?

Tags: sql, insert, deadlock

Assuming:

- I am using REPEATABLE_READ or SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation (locks get retained every time I access a row)
- We are talking about multiple threads accessing multiple tables simultaneously.

I have the following questions:

1. **Is it possible for an `INSERT` operation to cause  a deadlock?** If so, please provide a detailed scenario demonstrating how a deadlock may occur (e.g. Thread 1 does this, Thread 2 does that, ..., deadlock).
2. For bonus points: answer the same question for all other operations (e.g. SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE).

**UPDATE**: 
3. For super bonus points: how can I avoid a deadlock in the following scenario?

Given tables:

- permissions`[id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY]`
- companies`[id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30), permission_id BIGINT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (permission_id) REFERENCES permissions(id))`

I create a new Company as follows:

- INSERT INTO permissions; -- Inserts permissions.id = 100
- INSERT INTO companies (name, permission_id) VALUES ('Nintendo', 100); -- Inserts companies.id = 200

I delete a Company as follows:

- SELECT permission_id FROM companies WHERE id = 200; -- returns permission_id = 100
- DELETE FROM companies WHERE id = 200;
- DELETE FROM permissions WHERE id = 100;

In the above example, the INSERT locking order is [permissions, companies] whereas the DELETE locking order is [companies, permissions]. Is there a way to fix this example for `REPEATABLE_READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation?

Comment: A scenario defined as a single user (in a single transaction) inserting, selecting and deleting isn't going to cause a deadlock.

Comment: @CleverIdeaWidgetry, I've clarified the question to reflect the fact we're talking about multiple threads and tables.

Comment: The answer to your basic question "can it?" is yes - as others have said. Is there some obstacle preventing you from testing out your scenario yourself?

Comment: @CleverIdeaWidgetry, Just because it might work without deadlocks in my particular database doesn't mean it is guaranteed to work everywhere. Instead of saying "yes" I'd like for someone to provide a specific scenario that demonstrates an `INSERT` causing a deadlock.

Comment: Then DDD answered your question perfectly. If the insert is a multiple relation variety of `insert into C select A.value from A,B` then you can definitely have deadlocks. If the insert is a single relation variety `insert into C values (a_value)` then I can't imagine how it could. But, I defer to others to answer now that I understand your question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Generally all modifications can cause a deadlock and selects will not (get to that later).  So

1. No you cannot ignore these.
2. You can somewhat ignore select depending on your database and settings but the others will give you deadlocks.

You don't even need multiple tables.

The best way to create a deadlock is to do the same thing in a different order.

SQL Server examples:

```
create table A
(
    PK int primary key
)
```

Session 1:

```
begin transaction
insert into A values(1)
```

Session 2:

```
begin transaction    
insert into A values(7)
```

Session 1:

```
delete from A where PK=7
```

Session 2:

```
delete from A where PK=1
```

You will get a deadlock.  So that proved inserts & deletes can deadlock.

Updates are similar:

Session 1:

```
begin transaction    
insert into A values(1)
insert into A values(2)
commit

begin transaction
update A set PK=7 where PK=1
```

Session 2:

```
begin transaction
update A set pk=9 where pk=2    
update A set pk=8 where pk=1
```

Session 1:

```
update A set pk=9 where pk=2
```

Deadlock!

SELECT should never deadlock but on some databases it will because the locks it uses interfere with consistent reads.  That's just crappy database engine design though.

SQL Server will not lock on a SELECT if you use SNAPSHOT ISOLATION.  Oracle & I think Postgres will never lock on SELECT (unless you have FOR UPDATE which is clearly reserving for an update anyway).

So basically I think you have a few incorrect assumptions.  I think I've proved:

1. Updates can cause deadlocks
2. Deletes can cause deadlocks
3. Inserts can cause deadlocks
4. You do not need more than one table
5. You **do** need more than one session

You'll just have to take my word on SELECT ;)  but it will depend on your DB and settings.

Comment: First, thank you for having the decency to answer to question properly :) Secondly, I've added a third question for your review. Please see the updated question.

Comment: That doesn't look like it would work.  You can't delete the permission before the company as it's refereneced by the FK.

Comment: That scenario on its own should not deadlock.  When you combine it with lots of other things doing the same with the *same values* you might.
Serialise mode basically pretends you're single user and throws away stuff that behaves otherwise (not much better than a deadlock)
Repeatable Read is irrelevent

Comment: So to extrapolate your answer: so long as you don't access inserted rows before the transaction commits there is no way for an INSERT to cause a deadlock. In the case of #3 it's hard to imagine anyone looking up a permission row that was inserted but not committed since the only column is an auto-incremented id. Is that correct?

Comment: Generally that will be ok, yes.  However it does depend on other activity and your database and the settings.  It's really quite a complicated subject and one all too many developers don't bother to learn, so good on you for doing so.

Comment: SELECT can cause deadlock, but require a INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE partner, and yes crappy database engine around..

In some SELECT with a JOIN will acquire row locks for each tables, when it happens,  R1->R2 can cause deadlock with another thread which getting exclusive lock in reverse order W2->W1.

Even worst,  you might not control the locking order in the SELECT join SQL, which could be statistic or criteria based.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to LoztInSpace's answer, `inserts` may cause deadlocks even without `deletes` or `updates` presence. All you need is a unique index and a reversed operations order.

Example in Oracle :

```
create table t1 (id number);
create unique index t1_pk on t1 (id);

--thread 1 :
insert into t1 values(1);
--thread 2
insert into t1 values(2);
--thread 1 :
insert into t1 values(2);
--thread 2
insert into t1 values(1);  -- deadlock !
```

Comment: And what the solution?

Comment: I think that the simplest (but not always possible) solution would be to sort the rows before inserting.

Comment: Why would this cause a deadlock instead of a constraint violation and rollback on the thread 2 commit?

Comment: @KarlIvarDahl It wouldn't be correct to throw constraint violation to thread-2, because thread-1 hasn't committed yet and hence there is no violation.

Comment: can you explain a bit on why this would result in deadlock and why sorting fixes the problem?

Comment: @Steve The main idea here is that when two processes are trying to insert the same value into unique key column, one of them will be locked and will be waiting for the other one either to commit or to rollback. If you understand this point, the example above is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @GrishaWeintraub this only happen if its wrapped inside a transaction right? if no explicit transaction is set and the insert is running under auto commit mode this should make one thread throw dup key exception and bail right?

Comment: @Steve yes, it's only relevant for transactions. In general, I don't think you can have a deadlock when auto commit is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you have two relations `A` and `B` and two users `X` and `Y`. Table A is WRITE Locked by user X and Table B is WRITE Locked by Y. Then the following query will give you a dead lock if used by both the users X and Y.

```
Select * from A,B
```

So clearly a `Select` operation can cause a deadlock if join operations involving more than one table is a part of it. Usually Insert and Delete operations involve single relations. So they may not cause deadlock.

Comment: Please assume that all operations involve multiple tables (as demonstrated in the example) because clearly you cannot get deadlocks without doing so. To that end, which operations can cause deadlocks and which cannot. So far you've demonstrated how `SELECT` **can** cause deadlocks. Let's discuss the rest.

Comment: If there is a foreign key constraint between relations A and B,  A and B are locked by users X and Y respectively, then you might get a deadlock.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. I'm asking about **all** SQL operations, not just `SELECT`. I am mostly interested in `INSERT` but I expect you to discuss all other operation types as well.

Comment: My comment was about INSERT and DELETE operations. If the tables are locked and they both contain foreign keys then you might get a deadlock while using INSERT and DELETE.

Comment: I'm having a problem visualizing it. Please update your answer to include a step-by-step explanation (thread 1 does this, thread 2 does that, etc) of how a deadlock would occur for an `INSERT`. Thank you.