# Batch SQL instance, commit and rollback

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find how I am supposed to do this, someone can give me an explanation or show examples?

This is the question:

Start two Batch sql instances beside each other, to login twice in the same database and run two concurrent transactions. Show the effect of commit and rollback, and what happens if the two transactions try to commit conflicting changes. (Some hints can be found in the transaction example from the lecture.) Remember that by default, each SQL statement is considered its own transaction in Batch sql , and you have to give the command start transaction to start a multi-statement transaction.

I've tried to look around on the internet for an answer but since this question is broad it's kinda difficult for my level of understanding.

Comment: BSQL is batchSQL(BDSL is now changed, i typed wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do things like below and document/explain the results.

- Create a table
- Add some data into it
- Update the data
- Update different data in two separate concurrent transactions
- Update the same data in two separate concurrent transactions
- Update one unique row to be the same as another
- Set up a circular reference (deadlock). [Can an INSERT operation result in a deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534277/can-an-insert-operation-result-in-a-deadlock)

I suspect the last one is what they are after but I'm not your lecturer so hard to know :)  Have you tried asking for more clarity?